# Django админка

Tags: python, django-orm, django-admin

Пишу небольшое приложение.
Есть модель "Название проекта" (имя, дата), по внешнему ключу к ней подключается модель "Дни" (имя, внешний ключ к "Название проекта), а потом к модели "Дни" по внешнему ключу подключаются - "Задачи" (имя, текст, внешний ключ к "Задачи").
Не могу разобраться с отображением моделей в админке, хочу сделать так чтобы была иерархия, т.е. заходим в "Название проекта" и в этом окне задаем параметры проекта (имя и т.д.), ниже под ним "Дни" (как я понял за это отвечает StackedInLine), но как заставить отображаться "Задачи"??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не проще ли задачу линковать к проекту и дать ей поле дата? Функционал останется прежним, но минус 1 таблица в базе, а это многое упрощает